# Problem using Geogebra and Babel Spanish

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, geogebra

I'm new using Geogebra and Latex. I'm trying to insert a chart made with Geogebra. It works fine in Texnicenter when I paste the code, however, when I add [spanish]{babel}, I get as result a mistake (6, really).

This is my code:
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
hola
\clearpage
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.12941176470588237,0.12941176470588237,0.12941176470588237}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.7cm,y=0.7692307692307693cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.7cm,y=0.7692307692307693cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-5.0,
xmax=5.0,
ymin=-1.0,
ymax=12.0,
xtick={-5.0,-4.0,...,5.0},
ytick={-1.0,0.0,...,12.0},]
\clip(-5.,-1.) rectangle (5.,12.);
\draw[line width=2.pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-5.0:5.0] plot(\x,{(\x)^(2.0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please also post the error messages -- add them to the question using the "edit" facility.

Answer (score 3):

The cure for your problem is to load TikZ library `babel` in document preamble. It restore the meanings of some symbols changes by the package `babel`.

Beside this don't mix syntax of the `tikz` and the `pgfplots` packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
hola
\clearpage
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.12941176470588237,0.12941176470588237,0.12941176470588237}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.7cm,y=0.7692307692307693cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.7cm,y=0.7692307692307693cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-5.0,
xmax=5.0,
ymin=-1.0,
ymax=12.0,
xtick={-5.0,-4.0,...,5.0},
ytick={-1.0,0.0,...,12.0},]
%\clip(-5.,-1.) rectangle (5.,12.);
\addplot [line width=2.pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-5.0:5.0] {(\x)^(2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ¡That works great! Thank you so much!!